# Maven assembly plugin and adding system dependencies to the classpath

Tags: maven-2

I have some dependencies which I am providing myself. The jars are in the resources directory. In my pom they are scoped as system and I include the path to them. However, when I jar things up using the assembly plugin and use

```
<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
```

It doesn't add the path of the system jars. How can I get them to be included automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, and that's why using `system` scope is a bad practice. Have a look at [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path/2230464#2230464) (and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065928/maven-2-assembly-with-dependencies-jar-under-scope-system-not-included/2068101#2068101)) for a solution.