# exclude dependencies when running sonar analysis

Tags: maven-2, sonarqube

I have a test project requiring some heavy jars which i put in `${M2_HOME}\test\src\main\resources\` and add them in the pom.xml using :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>server</groupId>
        <artifactId>server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${M2_HOME}\test\src\main\resources\server.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>client</groupId>
        <artifactId>client</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${M2_HOME}\test\src\main\resources\client.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

I want to know if it possible to exclude them during sonar analysis, or generally just analyze java sources folder.

Comment: Why do you have system path deps? Why don't you use usual module dependencies or put them into a Maven Repository (e.g. Nexus etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that these JARs are included in sonar analysis because they are located in `src/main/resources`, then one obvious solution would be to put them somewhere else (see the post scriptum). If for whatever reason this is not possible, please clarify (I'd really like to know why you put these JARs under resources).

If the problem is that these JARs are declared as dependencies, you could use a specific profile not including them to run sonar.

PS: Note that using the `system` scope is a bad practice and has several drawbacks (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065928/maven-2-assembly-with-dependencies-jar-under-scope-system-not-included) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531354/maven-assembly-plugin-and-adding-system-dependencies-to-the-classpath)). A cleaner approach would be to use a file based repository as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path/2230464#2230464).

Comment: thank you works great !  but what if i dont want to copy jars into maven repository ? and using 'em from enterprise repository to avoid duplication

Comment: @achraf I'm not sure to get the question. What would that change?

Comment: we have a quit heavy custom lib so just to save disk space

Comment: @achraf Ok, I get that. But from a Maven dependency point of view, I don't think it would change anything (just the repository location). Unless I missed something.

Comment: not just the repository location but also the possibility to use a secondary rep !