# How to include local jar files in Maven project

Tags: java, maven-2, netbeans, jar

I do not want to install a few jars into a Maven repository (both local/remote). In particular I have a few jar files located in

```
c:\work\projects\myapp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\test.jar

c:\work\projects\myapp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\test2.jar
```

How to include them into my project when open/edit with NetBeans?

Comment: I wish I could destroy, burn, send to hell all these questions promoting using `system` scoped dependencies. I keep writing [against this practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642023/having-a-3rd-party-jar-included-in-maven-shaded-jar-without-adding-it-to-local-re/3643308#3643308) but sadly, it doesn't help...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you considered adding those two JARs as [`system` dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies)?  e.g.,

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

Just a word of note, this is NOT recommended and should be used very sparingly, if ever.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent: I up-voted your comment despite your statement that I should get a -10. :)  I totally agree with you.  I wrote my answer under the assumption that @cometta has his/her reasons for using it.  Personally, I hate it when someone goes "but you shouldn't do that!" when I ask a question.  I'll update my answer to mention that's it's highly unrecommended.

Comment: Maybe the last part of my comment was not necessary (note that I actually didn't downvote your answer). At least, it was not a call for punishment but more a scream of frustration :) I will repost a more friendly version.

Comment: This is really an **evil** practice strongly [discouraged](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Dependency+Scopes). Every time someone use this, God kills a Maven developer.

Comment: I do not share the fervor with which you do not recommend this practice. In the context of a source-controlled build, lack of access to a local maven repo, and a team project, this is the only sane solution to providing a dependency not available in public repos...

Comment: @jfernand - *"... this is the only sane solution ..."*,  Actually, it is not the only sane solution.  See the other answers.

Comment: this <id>data-local</id> approach works with <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>, while the <scope>system</scope> approach does not

Answer (score 68):

### Although it works to use the systemPath reference, it is better to create a local repository.  And fortunately, it is easy to do.

**Creating a local repository holding jars not available in a public repository**

NOTE:  I use Eclipse, so some of the instructions are specific to Eclipse.  Most are easily generalizable.

---

### Assumptions

- The jar was created by Maven in another project with the following...

  ```
  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  ```

---

### In Project (that wants to access the jars)

- Create repo directory just off the project base directory
- For each jar to be accessed locally...

  - add directories for each level of the groupID (ex. /repo**/com/foo**)
  - add jar name (aka artifactId) without the version (ex. /repo/com/foo**/test**)
  - add directory for the version of the jar (ex. /repo/com/foo/test**/0.1.1**)
  - put the jar in that directory (ex. /repo/com/foo/test/0.1.1**/test-0.1.1.jar**)

---

### In pom.xml (for the project that wants to access the jars)

- Define the local repository

  ```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>data-local</id>
      <name>data</name>
      <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ```
- Add the dependency on the local jar.  From our example above, this would be...

  ```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

---

### Rebuild

- Rt click pom.xml -> Run as -> Maven build

Comment: What do you need to do if you only want to give access to the jars in a sub module? I followed the instructions, and added the repository definition to my sub module pom, but maven seems to ignore this repository when building.

Comment: Damn, my packaging was `pom` which was not letting it import. Making it `jar` followed by `mvn clean install -U` makes it available to add as maven `<dependency>`.

Comment: This is the correct answer; it follows the Maven ideology, and works like a charm.

Comment: um, for Maven 3, there are a few more things that have to be done, like renaming jar to include version number, and adding a pom file to each of these directories. luckily someone already wrote about it here https://gist.github.com/timmolderez/92bea7cc90201cd3273a07cf21d119eb

Comment: this approach works with <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>, while the <scope>system</scope> approach does not.

Comment: @hello_earth although with Maven 3 the jar needs the version number as suffix in its name, there is **no need** for additional pom(s)!

Answer (score 14):

In the past, I've done this by creating a "local" repository directory tree in the project itself, and referring to it in the POM by declaring a local repository with a project relative path.

But that is a hack.  (Maybe not so hacky - per @Pascal's comment.  I'm still a bit of a Maven novice, despite using it for a year or so.)

Comment: That's a muuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuch better *solution* than the evil system scope **hack**. People keep using the system scope (and recommending it) without understanding how it hurts... This is depressing.

Comment: Nice to hear this worked for you. Could you perhaps update your answer to explain how I could make this technique work for me?

Answer (score 7):

None of the other answers worked for me.  I had to run a slightly different command...

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file:///path/to/yourproject/repo/ -Dfile=mylib-1.0.jar -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=mylib -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.0
```

See complete steps in this article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies

Comment: If you have a pom.xml file for your local jar (e.g., because you built it yourself) then you can use `-DpomFile=<path-to-pom>` to point at that. The `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version` and `packaging` arguments are then picked up from the pom file. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html.