# How to add a Java Project as a dependecy Project for Maven Web Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I converted a Simple Web Project **A** as a Maven Web Project ,But Project **A** is depend on a Simple Java Project **B** So in Dynamic Web Project i added this project into **Java Build Path** of my project .But now i converted project **A** as Maven Web Project .

My Question is that how can I add this **B** Project as a dependency project for  Maven Web Project **A**. So it will run without any issue.
Thanks

Comment: Add the jar generated by **B** in the classpath of **A** (like normal application). Otherwise, you can add a maven reference to **B** jar as showed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3765903/1065197)

Comment: Is there any other way to add that project because it is also a live project so lots of changes going on daily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project B should be a maven project too. You can add the dependency into maven project A.

If you don´t want to convert B into maven project, you can copy your b.jar into your .m2/repository and then you can add the dependency into maven project A. Copy the b.jar as a jar generated by maven, is, .m2/repository/somegroupid/b/1.0/b-1.0.jar