# Jess "Class not found" exception at Maven project

Tags: java, maven, jess

First of all I want to say this is kind of a follow up of a question I posted yesterday which I solved myself ([How to add Jess in Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115103/how-to-add-jess-in-maven-project)).

This time, it's Jess' turn to have problems finding the project's classes. More specifically, everything runs fine until the execution of the 1st line of engine.batch("rules.clp"), where I get a "Class not found exception".

```
(import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.examples.huntbot)
(deftemplate HunterBot (declare (from-class HunterBot)))
```

The package structure is:

```
-cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.examples.huntbot
-- HunterBot.java
```

Below are the first lines of the HunterBot.java file:

```
package cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.examples.huntbot;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import jess.*;
import cz.cuni.amis.introspection.java.JProp;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.base.agent.navigation.IPathExecutorState;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.base.communication.worldview.listener.annotation.EventListener;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.base.utils.Pogamut;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.base.utils.guice.AgentScoped;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.base.utils.math.DistanceUtils;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.base3d.worldview.object.ILocated;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.agent.module.utils.TabooSet;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.agent.navigation.UT2004PathAutoFixer;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.agent.navigation.stuckdetector.UT2004DistanceStuckDetector;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.agent.navigation.stuckdetector.UT2004PositionStuckDetector;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.agent.navigation.stuckdetector.UT2004TimeStuckDetector;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.bot.impl.UT2004Bot;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.bot.impl.UT2004BotModuleController;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.ItemType;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.UT2004ItemType;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbcommands.Initialize;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbcommands.Move;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbcommands.Rotate;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbcommands.Stop;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbcommands.StopShooting;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbinfomessages.BotDamaged;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbinfomessages.BotKilled;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbinfomessages.Item;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbinfomessages.NavPoint;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbinfomessages.Player;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbinfomessages.PlayerDamaged;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbinfomessages.PlayerKilled;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.utils.UT2004BotRunner;
import cz.cuni.amis.utils.exception.PogamutException;
import cz.cuni.amis.utils.flag.FlagListener;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * Example of Simple Pogamut bot, that randomly walks around the map searching for preys shooting at everything that is in its way.
 *
 * @author Rudolf Kadlec aka ik
 * @author Jimmy
 */
@AgentScoped
public class HunterBot extends UT2004BotModuleController<UT2004Bot> {

     Rete engine;
...
```

And finally this is the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004</groupId>
        <artifactId>pogamut-ut2004-bot-pom</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>huntbot</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>04-hunter-bot</name>
    <url>http://pogamut.cuni.cz</url>

    <properties>
        <bot.main.class>cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.examples.huntbot.HunterBot</bot.main.class>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>amis-artifactory</id>
            <name>AMIS Artifactory</name>
            <url>http://diana.ms.mff.cuni.cz:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
        </repository>


               <repository>
                    <id>data-local</id>
                    <name>data</name>
                   <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
               </repository>

    </repositories>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
                <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${bot.main.class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


        <dependencies>

         <dependency>
          <groupId>gov.sandia</groupId>
          <artifactId>jess</artifactId>
          <version>7.1p2</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
         </dependency>

          </dependencies>


</project>
```

The jess-7.1p2.jar file is located at (base.dir)\repo\gov\sandia\jess\7.1p2\ . It is recognized without problems.

PS: I tried to make this question as detailed as possible. If more info is needed, I can provide it immediately.

Comment: Shouldn't you `(import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.examples.huntbot.Hunterbot)`? In Java usually you should specify the class(and method) name or import with `.*`.

Answer (score 1):

The import function permits both for importing a single class or all classes in a package. A package alone can't be imported - it doesn't make sense.

```
(import some.pack.SomeClass)
```

and

```
(import another.pack.*)
```

If you need access to the static members of a class you *must* use the specific form. The statics are then available as if they were a user function:

```
(SomeClass.MAX_NUMBER_OF_X)
```