# How to use Jess (Rule Engine for the Java) with Java Maven Project?

Tags: java, maven-3, jess

I wanted to create a simple maven java project to use Jess (Rule Engine for the Java), but I don't see any dependency is present for this to use `import jess.*;`

I did google for Jess library to use with Java Maven project, I don't see it's free to use it.

1) Could anyone please provide steps to create it? Or Can we run from command prompt?

2) Is there any site by which has basic sample program and some complex stuff?

Comment: I am not sure wheather or not maven dependency for **Jess** is present or not but
[You can add jars in Maven Based Project without installing them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3765955/3143670)

Comment: Note that Jess isn't open source, so there won't be a Maven dependency for general availability. If you are with one of the (mainly educational) organizations that are legally permitted to use Jess, your IT department might set it up in your org's local Maven repo. Otherwise, roll your own.

Comment: Jess is not free. You have to buy liscence. However, you can download trial version. Jess is only one jar called jess.jar. So, you can use mvn install command to install it locally and include it in your pom dependencies as usual