# Adding a system dependency to Maven

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I am working with Apache Spark through Maven, and I am trying to modify the source by including a 3rd party jar and trying to utilize some methods within it.

I get the following error when compiling the Spark project using

```sh
mvn -Dhadoop.version=2.2.0 -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTests clean package
```

```
not found: object edu
[ERROR] import edu.xxx.cs.aggr._
```

I modified `ResultTask.scala` to contain an import statement. So, maven is unable to find the jar I am trying to use and link it with the project.

I have added a dependency to the pom.xml file such as this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.xxx.cs</groupId>
    <artifactId>aggr</artifactId>
    <version>0.99</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/aggr.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

The jar file I am trying to link is located in the same directory as the spark pom.xml file. I added this dependency to pom.xml. I inserted it in between 2 existing dependencies within the pom.xml file. I'm not sure whats wrong, but I would just like the jar to get linked for now, so that I can use the methods within it. I'm also not sure if I should be using anything specific for the groupId, artifactId, and version. edu.xxx.cs.aggr is the root package which contains other source files and packages. I would appreciate any help.

**UPDATE**

I used

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=edu.xxx.cs -DartifactId=aggr -Dversion=0.99 -Dpackaging=jar to install the jar to the .m2 repo. I checked the repo to see if it was installed, and it was.
```

I changed the dependency in pom.xml to

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>edu.purdue.cs</groupId>
        <artifactId>aggr</artifactId>
        <version>0.99</version>
</dependency>
```

I still get the same error.

Comment: Try manually adding it to your local maven repository in location <m2repo>/edu/xxx/cs/aggr/0.99/aggr-0.99.jar

Comment: That's a wrong way and there is no guarantee it will work always. Maven provide its native solutions instead of changing its artifacts base manually.

Comment: If you open up that aggr.jar file in a zip tool, IS there actually a directory 'edu' in there I wonder?

Comment: I've used this jar in a simple java project that I have created on eclipse. The import statement edu.xxx.cs.aggr doesn't produce any errors in that project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is how I add system dependency to my maven pom.xml. with in the project root path, I have created lib directory and there I have placed my jar file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sshx</groupId>
    <artifactId>sshx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/sshxcute-1.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

if still you face the same issue try adding the dependency manually by issuing the following command from the jar file location

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sshxcute-1.0.jar -DgroupId=com.sshx -DartifactId=sshx -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

this command will add the jar to your .m2 repository as a dependency and you need to change the pom.xml dependency as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sshx</groupId>
    <artifactId>sshx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

once you are done, issue `mvn clean install` command from command prompt and build your application.

However, another option is to create a local repository. See at this thread: 
[How to include local jar files in Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19226672)

Comment: I manually added the jar file to my .m2 repo. Now, it is under the proper directories and the jar is there. But, I still get this error

Comment: does manually means issuing the **mvn install** command?? have you updated your dependency in your pom.xml file as mentioned above?

Comment: I used mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=edu.xxx.cs -DartifactId=aggr -Dversion=0.99 -Dpackaging=jar

I changed the dependency to 

<dependency>
        <groupId>edu.xxx.cs</groupId>
        <artifactId>aggr</artifactId>
        <version>0.99</version>
      </dependency>

Comment: try to refresh your project once from IDE or issue **mvn clean install** command and try

Comment: I don't have this setup on an IDE. I am making changes via sublime and building using mvn. So, I should just use mvn clean install from the dir that contains pom.xml?

Comment: yes, you need to use mvn clean install to re-build the project so that your changes take effect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78307/discussion-between-androiddev93-and-prasad-khode).

Comment: Simplest solution is to start using a repository manager and install that artifact there. Afterwards use it as any other dependency without system scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the filename into the variable. For what I know you may not mix variables and paths within the systemPath parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There must be several options but the only way.
The way depends on how Maven really works. It works with dependency repositories.
So to compile successfully you need to specify valid repository for you JAR.
You can use your local repository for this. To add JAR there you can invoke "mvn install" command for that JAR.
As an alternative you can specify in your POM file the location of local repository to use for Maven.

Answer (score 0):

You can install your Jar to local maven repository by using following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

Comment: I manually added the jar to the local repo. I created the appropriate directory structure <m2repo>/edu/xxx/cs/aggr/0.99/aggr-0.99.jar. I compiled again and I still got the same error

Comment: don't try to create it manually. Just use command it will create it for you automatically. I think this command will create some 2-3 supporting files with the jar.

Comment: Thats what I did. I used mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=edu.xxx.cs -DartifactId=aggr -Dversion=0.99 -Dpackaging=jar

Comment: after installing the jar don't forget to refresh the project. or try `mvn clean`

Comment: when I build the project I already use clean by doing mvn -Dhadoop.version=2.2.0 -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTests clean package. I tried mvn clean before building it, I still get the error.