# Include local jar file in maven project - not finding file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, pom.xml

So I'm trying to include two local jar files into a Maven project I have and failing to do so. I've tried working through the solutions in these threads: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765903/how-to-include-local-jar-files-in-maven-project) but it still isn't really working. Here are the key pieces of my pom.xml file:

```
    <repository>
        <id>local-maven-repo</id>
        <url>file://${basedir}/resources</url>
    </repository>
```

and then dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.mlab.jar1</groupId>
        <artifactId>jar1_local</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.mlab.jar2</groupId>
        <artifactId>jar2_local</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Both jar files include package declarations at `edu.mlab.jar1` and `edu.mlab.jar2` respectively, so that's where I want them. The jar files are in the resources folder, and that's right under the base directory.

That's the setup. Now, when I try `mvn package` (after `mvn clean`) I get the following error

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project PROJECT: Could not resolve dependencies for project edu.mlab.project:PROJECT:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: edu.mlab.jar1:jar1_local:jar:1.0, edu.mlab.jar2:jar2_local:jar:1.0: Failure to find edu.mlab.jar1:jar1_local:jar:1.0 in file:///Users/mlab/Desktop/2016/project_web/resources was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of local-maven-repo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]`

I'm not really sure what's going wrong seeing as my jar1 and jar2 are exactly in the resources folder. Also, I've tried the approach of importing them with the system scope, but that won't work for my purposes as I want them included in the war artifact.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you the file here file:///Users/mlab/Desktop/2016/project_web/resources/edu/mlab/jar1/jar1_local/jar1_local-1.0.jar  ?

Comment: No, I don't, but isn't the package declaration supposed to take care of that?

Comment: I have reedited the path. No, Maven search jar in groupId/artifactId/artifactId-version.jar where groupid must be split with directory for each dot character.
Try :)

Comment: I tried making such a folder, but it doesn't seem like it fixes anything. The error still has it looking in `resources`

Answer (score 1):

1. First try to install those two jar files into `Maven`'s local repository using the command below

---

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file  -Dfile=path-to-your-artifact-jar \
                                                                              -DgroupId=your.groupId \
                                                                              -DartifactId=your-artifactId \
                                                                              -Dversion=version \
                                                                              -Dpackaging=jar \
                                                                              -DlocalRepositoryPath=path-to-specific-local-repo
```

Reference URL: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html

**Note:** your local `Maven` repository is specified in the installation $M2_HOME\conf\settings.xml e.g.

```
<localRepository>C:\local_maven_repo</localRepository>
```

2. Then use the regular `Maven` tags

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>your.groupId</groupId>
       <artifactId>your-artifactId</artifactId>
       <version>your-version</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Comment: Does this still hold if I'm trying to create a war artifact?

Comment: These two jar files will be included into the WEB-INF/lib in the war file.

Comment: Ok, and in this context what's the groupID/artifactID I want to set?

Comment: groupId for both jar files are **edu.mlab**, and version for both jar files are **1.0**, and artifactId for jar 1 is **jar1** and for jar 2 is **jar2**. You may rename later.

Comment: Hi, I just tried doing this thing again checking that everything is correctly set up, and a couple of strange things happened. 1) nothing shows up in my $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml about this particular repository. 2) How do I rename it? 3) It seems to have just randomly picked a folder, named it to my groupID and claim its a jar instead of actually finding Jar1. Anything I can do?

Answer (score 1):

**Assumption:** You're using `Windows` and your jar1 & jar2 is in C:\Users\yourusername
   folder

1. Set your **M2_HOME** environment variable, e.g.

   `C:\Users\yourusername>set M2_HOME=C:\apache-maven-3.3.9
    C:\Users\yourusername>echo %M2_HOME%
    C:\apache-maven-3.3.9`
2. Manually create a folder C:\local_maven_repo then edit edit file

   C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\conf\settings.xml as below
   [image]
3. run the **mvn** command to instal jar1 & jar2 into C:\local_maven_repo, e.g.

`C:\Users\yourusername>mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file  -Dfile=jar1.jar -DgroupId=edu.mlab -DartifactId=jar1 -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DlocalRepositoryPath=C:\local_maven_repo`

`C:\Users\yourusername>mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file  -Dfile=jar2.jar -DgroupId=edu.mlab -DartifactId=jar2 -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DlocalRepositoryPath=C:\local_maven_repo`

4. Verify the jar1 & jar2 is in the C:\local_maven_repo, e.g.

`C:\Users\yourusername>dir C:\local_maven_repo\edu\mlab\jar1\1.0\`

`C:\Users\yourusername>dir C:\local_maven_repo\edu\mlab\jar2\1.0\`

5. Open files C:\local_maven_repo\edu\mlab\jar1\1.0\jar1-1.0.pom, and C:\local_maven_repo\edu\mlab\jar2\1.0\jar2-1.0.pom

---

file: C:\local_maven_repo\edu\mlab\jar1\1.0\jar1-1.0.pom

```
  <groupId>edu.mlab</groupId>
  <artifactId>jar1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
```

file: C:\local_maven_repo\edu\mlab\jar2\1.0\jar2-1.0.pom

```
  <groupId>edu.mlab</groupId>
  <artifactId>jar2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
```

copy the following and include them in your pom.xml as below

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.mlab</groupId>
  <artifactId>jar1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
<dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.mlab</groupId>
  <artifactId>jar2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
<dependency>
```