# Load jar into project with maven

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, gwt

My app needs to serve a servlet like this:

```
serve("_ah/admin/datastore*").with(DatastoreViewerServlet.class);
```

However, this `DatastoreViewerServlet` is located in a runtime sdk located in my machine:

```
some_path/lib/shared/appengine-local-runtime-shared.jar
```

So how can I load this jar when I run my application. I am using maven, and when I run my application I just do `mvn gwt:run`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use systemPath tag inside dependency tag. Please try the following.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.gae</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-local-runtime-shared</artifactId>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>some_path/lib/shared/appengine-local-runtime-shared.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Right now I'm still having an issue with serving it with 'serve' method

Comment: OK, if I pust this dependency, and removed serve("/_ah/admin/datastore") then access the datastore viewer like the usual way: here's what I get:

Could not find resource for relative : /_ah/admin/datastore of full path: http://127.0.0.1:8888/_ah/admin/datastore

Comment: I didn't worked on GWT much apart from the example application eclipse created so I'm guesing. If _ah is not your application context root then the context path is missing while looking up the resource. Please post a new question you will get help quicker.

Comment: Don't use System scope. Install the dependency with `install:install-file` See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642023/having-a-3rd-party-jar-included-in-maven-shaded-jar-without-adding-it-to-local-r