# maven-shade-plugin : how add all dependencies and custom local jar to executable jar?

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

Maven 3
Java 1.8

In my pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myproject/groupId>
            <artifactId>mixed-pojo</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/external-pojo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
...
```

I need to create **ONE executable jar**. So I use plugin  `maven-shade-plugin`
here pom's snippet:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>com.myproject.AppStarterKt</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <artifactSet>
                        <includes>
                            <include>${project.basedir}/libs/external-pojo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</include>
                            <include>com.zaxxer:HikariCP</include>
                        </includes>
                    </artifactSet>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

As result it generate `executable jar`:

```
myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
```

Nice. 
But the problem is that I need manually add ALL dependencies in plugin like this:

```
<artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>${project.basedir}/libs/external-pojo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</include>
                                    <include>com.zaxxer:HikariCP</include>
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>
```

But I has **50** dependencies. How add ALL dependencies to executable jar?

P.S.

```
external-pojo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

is a external custom jar that locate on project's folder  `/libs`

Answer (score 2):

By default all `runtime` scoped dependencies will be included in the shaded uber JAR. Remove `<artifactSet>` from the `<configuration>` to get default behavior.

`<artifactSet>` configuration option is used to override the defaults. When specified `<includes>` option is a white list of artifacts to include.

Since plugin version 1.3 you can use wildcards `*` and `?`, but this shouldn't be necessary in your example:

```
<includes>
  <include>**</include>
</includes>
```

Comment: It's success included all dependencies. But not include my custom jar. How I can do this?

Comment: Remove `<scope>system</scope>` and install this dependency into local repo using [`mvn install`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html). This will also reduce the duplication, you won't have to specify the path twice. [System scope is not suitable for shade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3643308/1602555).