# Add jar (dependency with scope system) in an Ear build

Tags: maven-2

I work with **Maven** and I want to do a build with packaging **ear**, i want to add a dependency with **scope** system and also with specifing the **systemPath** of the jar like follow:

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>group1</groupId> 
  <artifactId>group1</artifactId> 
  <version>1</version> 
  <scope>system</scope> 
  <systemPath>D:\Buildear\Jars\file.jar</systemPath> 
</dependency>
```

But I don't found the jar in my generater ear!!!

Help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I work with Maven and I want to do a build with packaging ear, I want to add a dependency with scope `system` (...). But I don't found the jar in my generater ear!!!

Yes, that's just what you get when (ab)using a `system` scoped dependency which is supposed to be always available **by definition**. I wrote many times about this, for example in this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642023/having-a-3rd-party-jar-included-in-maven-shaded-jar-without-adding-it-to-local-re/3643308#3643308) that I'm quoting below:

> I already wrote [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280834/local-jars-are-not-included-in-class-path/3281409#3281409), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588502/maven-assembly-plugin-doesnt-add-dependencies-with-system-scope),
>   [really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531354/maven-assembly-plugin-and-adding-system-dependencies-to-the-classpath) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065928/maven-2-assembly-with-dependencies-jar-under-scope-system-not-included) times about this
>   here on SO and in 99% of the cases,
>   `system` scoped dependencies should be
>   avoided. And I'll repeat what the
>   [Dependency Scopes](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Dependency+Scopes) mini guide says
>   one more time:
>
> > - **`system`**: This dependency is required in some phase of your
> >       project's lifecycle, but is
> >       system-specific. **Use of this scope
> >       is discouraged: This is considered an
> >       "advanced" kind of feature and should
> >       only be used when you truly understand
> >       all the ramifications of its use,
> >       which can be extremely hard if not
> >       actually impossible to quantify.**
> >       This scope by definition renders your
> >       build non-portable. It may be
> >       necessary in certain edge cases. The
> >       system scope includes the
> >       `<systemPath>` element which points to
> >       the physical location of this
> >       dependency on the local machine. It is
> >       thus used to refer to some artifact
> >       expected to be present on the given
> >       local machine an not in a repository;
> >       and whose path may vary
> >       machine-to-machine. The systemPath
> >       element can refer to environment
> >       variables in its path: `${JAVA_HOME}`
> >       for instance.
>
> So, instead of using the `system`
>   scope, either:
>
> - Add your libraries to your local repository via `install:install-file`.
>     This is a quick and dirty way to get
>     things working, it might be an option
>     if you're alone but it makes your
>     build non portable.
> - Install and run an "enterprise repository" like Nexus, Archiva, or
>     Artifactory and add your libraries via
>     `deploy:deploy-file`. This is the
>     **ideal** scenario.
> - Setup a file based repository as described in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path/2230464#2230464)
>     and put your libraries in there. This
>     is the **best** compromise if you
>     don't have a corporate repository but
>     need to work as a team and don't want
>     to sacrifice portability.
>
> Please, stop using the `system` scope.

Comment: Okay i see, so i'll use install:install-file, my problem is that i have many dependencies that will take many time to install and then to add as dependency in the pom! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>aaa</artifactId>
    <groupId>aaa</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>aaa</groupId>
<artifactId>aaa</artifactId>
<version></version>

<packaging>ear</packaging>
<name>aaa - Ear</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>aaa-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>aaa-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-common</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbosssx</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${aaa.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <generateApplicationXml>false</generateApplicationXml>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <modules>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aaa-ejb</artifactId>
                    </ejbModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                        <excluded>true</excluded>
                    </jarModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <aaa.name>aaa-batch</aaa.name>
</properties>
```

This creates an ear and copies the libraries into the lib folder in the ear.

Comment: Yes, but i want to add a dependency and specify the path of the jar and i found that for specifing the path of the jar the scope should be system!! and i want that the jar with the scope system will be copied in my generated ear!

Comment: Also please, there is a way to hide the version of the jar after the build with packaging type "ear" for example if i use junit with version 5 i want to get it in my ear with the name junit and without the version in the name!