# Ninja Framework Include External Jar

Tags: java, maven, heroku, intellij-idea, ninjaframework

I have an external jar I wish to add to my [ninja framework](http://www.ninjaframework.org) application.

I have included the file in the root directory, which didn't work.

I also tried to include it as a dependency using IntelliJ IDE.

This also didn't work. On deployment to heroku, the compile failed, as the package couldn't be found.

Lastly, I tried this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies#deploy-the-artifact-into-the-repo, but it failed with this error message:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy-file (default-cli) on project 1.0: No transfer protocol found. -> [Help 1]
```

Can anyone suggest anything else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a question regarding Ninja, but more a question regarding the build system - Maven in that case.

And that question is fortunately already answered:

[Maven: Add local dependencies to jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354301/maven-add-local-dependencies-to-jar)

and also here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies