# How add local dependecy in assembly JAR

Tags: maven, build, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multimodule Maven project with several dependencies. I want to build a *fat* executable JAR containing them as well as my own compiled classes. I found [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/index.html) to be just what I needed except one nasty problem.

Some of my dependencies are local and distributed with project sources. I use `system` scope for them. It looks something like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
    <artifactId>forms_rt</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/forms_rt.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

The problem is that for some reason *these libraries aren't unpacked and bundled with the rest of dependencies* in result JAR.

I know that usage of `system` scope is considered bad practice, and in fact I even can find *some* of them (though quite outdated) in Maven repositories, but anyway it puzzles me how it can be solved with maven-assembly-plugin.

Just in case my plugin configuration looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>repoll.server.Repoll</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <finalName>${project.build.finalName}-full</finalName>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

As I understood I have to write custom descriptor, which e.g. includes and unpacks all JARs from `${project.basedir}/lib` directory, but after several unsuccessful attempts I still don't know how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to find solution here. It's described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065928/maven-2-assembly-with-dependencies-jar-under-scope-system-not-included).

In short, the whole problem was in usage of `system` scope. It turned out, that such dependencies  are filtered out by default, which I found out by running `mvn package` with debug output enabled (`-X/--debug`).
When *local repository* is defined for these JARs, distributed with project, they are unpacked by maven-assembly-plugin as exepected.