# What is the best way of adding a jar file to a maven project if we could not find it the maven central repository?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I need to add the package "`uk.ac.shef.wit.simmetrics.similaritymetrics`"
to my maven project but I am not able to find any remote repository which contains it. I have to add it via dependency to the project, but not successful yet.

-I already added the jar file to the referenced library but in that wat I get the following error:

```
package uk.ac.shef.wit.simmetrics.similaritymetrics does not exist.
```

-Adding it through following dependency to the Pom.xml also does not help

```
   <dependency> 
        <groupId>uk.ac.shef.wit</groupId>
        <artifactId>simmetrics</artifactId>
        version>1.6.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>LocalPath\simmetrics-1.6.2.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Set up an internal private repository manager.

Comment: Maybe https://jitpack.io/#magsilva/SimMetrics it seems to be on github and jitpack magically turns almost anything on github into a maven repository

Comment: Are you looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/2612910/3124333 ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a small project that you intend to only build locally or on a few machines then the simplest way is follow directions at the site below to add a 3rd party jar.  Those instructions will help you install it in your local repository.    You will need to do that for all machines that you intend to run the build on.
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

If you plan to run it on many machines then the best thing to do is to install the artifact to your own private repository.  If that is the case then I suggest you create a project for it in version control.  Then upload the file as part of that project.

Answer (score 1):

I appear to be the current maintainer of Simmetrics. You can add this dependency to your pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.mpkorstanje</groupId>
    <artifactId>simmetrics-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Simmetrics has been given a much needed serious overhaul since 1.6.2. You may have to adjust your code accordingly. For source code and documentation see https://github.com/Simmetrics/simmetrics