# Apache Nifi failure due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in a local maven dependency jar.

Tags: java, maven, apache-nifi

This is the first time I am using maven, I want to implement a processor for apache-nifi. Now for this I am using a proprietary jar file which is an SDK. It is not on the repositories. Therefore i have put it in the `pom.xml` as follows.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>KS</groupId>
        <artifactId>En-SDK</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/En-SDK-Java.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I am using `intelliJ` which seem to have no problem importing this dependency. So is the maven build procedure.

I use `mvn clean install` as explained in [this tutorial](http://www.nifi.rocks/developing-a-custom-apache-nifi-processor-json/). Which gives me with a `nar` package as the output. (no build errors)

This `nar` , which is supposed to be put in the `$NIFI_HOME/lib` directory does not bundle the said local jar.

If i place this nar file in the required directory and start `apache-nifi`,

```
 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /..././work/nar/extensions/myNar.nar
```

Seems to be loaded by the `NarClassLoaders` , but following that I get an exception and `nifi` doesn't start.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/kls/../../SubscriptionInterface
```

The `SubscriptionInterface` is a class from the said local jar.

If I look at the `nar` file's folder structure, inside the `META-INF/bundled-dependencies/` i see every other dependant jar files defined in the pom but not this local jar i used.

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Stackoverflow question seems to be similar to what you have asked. 
[Maven 2 assembly with dependencies: jar under scope "system" not included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065928/maven-2-assembly-with-dependencies-jar-under-scope-system-not-included)

Try to put the dependency in a local repository and declare it in the pom.