# Failure to launch NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, noclassdeffounderror

I have added some jar files to nifi lib folder to allow me to connect hive but unfortunately the nifi app not running in web , then I removed all the new jar files but the issue not fixed and I keep getting the following error (NIFI version 1.15.0)

ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to launch NiFi due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/nifi/processor/DataUnit

Comment: What version of Java are you using? NiFi requires Java 8 or Java 11 (https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/)

Comment: currently using java 8

Comment: the obvious solution - reinstall nifi maybe you have removed some necessary jar files.

Comment: Maybe but , Iam keep the reinstall as last option

Comment: To avoid potential issues, you can put custom jars into a separate folder and reference it in `nifi.properties` via `nifi.nar.library.directory.<custom>=<myFolder>`. See https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#installing-custom-processors

Answer (score 0):

I did find this answer that seems to point to the need to have declared the file in the pom. [Apache Nifi failure due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in a local maven dependency jar.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354877/apache-nifi-failure-due-to-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-in-a-local-maven-depen)