# ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//174.23.0.187:1111/qwe]

Tags: java, maven, soapui

After updating maven plugin to version 5.1.2 I get an error message

```
$ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//174.23.0.187:1111/qwe], see error log for details
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//174.23.0.187:1111/qwe
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(Sql.java:398)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(Sql.java:442)
    at groovy.sql.Sql$newInstance.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
...
```

Comment: Looks like you miss the Oracle Driver jar in your classpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

register JDBC driver solved the issue
`com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver( "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" )`

Answer (score 1):

You need to include oracle jdbc driver to your classpath, which you can download from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html)

Since you've a maven project the most normal thing to do was to simply include the dependency in your `pom.xml`, however due to the oracle jdbc licence there is no public repository with this jar, however recently (a few days ago) oracle adds this jar to their repository. You can try with it following the details on [oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/oracle_maven_repository_instructions_for) (note that user auth is required and maven version 3.2.5 o higher).

Comment: Typical Oracle: so they create a Maven repo, but lock it up ... so it makes it painful to use with a project. Good to know in any case.

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not want to use the *password locked* Oracle repo, you can do the following:

1. Download the O-JDBC from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/).
2. Place it in your project. Somewhere like a `lib` directory.
3. Use the `maven-install-plugin` to install the jar in your local repo. Something like this:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.4</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>install-ojdbc7</id>
               <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
               <configuration>
                   <file>lib/ojdbc7.jar</file>
                   <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                   <groupId>oracle.jdbc</groupId>
                   <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
                   <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
                   <packaging>jar</packaging>
                   <generatePom>true</generatePom>
               </configuration>
               <goals>
                   <goal>install-file</goal>
               </goals>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

The details of how this works are discussed little further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612910/3124333).

4. For your SoapUI, you will then need to link in the dependency:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
       <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>${soapui-maven-plugin.version}</version>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>oracle.jdbc</groupId>
               <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
               <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <phase>integration-test</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>test</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
               ...
               </configuration>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```
5. I am using `mvn verify` to run all this.

Comment: yeah install in the local repo is the way `:)`, since connect to oracle repo is too painful for only one jar.

Comment: @albciff Oracle still trying to completely kill of Java. :)