# How to add external folder that contains multiple jars into maven build for web application?

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, maven-plugin, maven-bundle-plugin

I'm using `intellij` with tomcat server to deploy my spring mvc application, i have another 3-th party jars (10) that i would like to add them to the war file while packing it with maven, is there a way to tell maven -> Include all these jars in this folder?

Comment: Don't do that - it's not really what Maven is for. List each jar separately and get them from maven central or somwewhere similar, not your hard-drive. Your approach won't work in a team and won't work for future developers. If you don't have a team, don't care about the future, and don't want to follow the standard maven way of doing things, then perhaps you shouldn't be using maven.

Comment: the problem is that i'm using eBay SDK, i did not find it in any repo beside ebay releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no option to include every jar in a folder,if you want to include individual jar's from the file system:

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
          <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.0</version>
          <scope>system</scope>
          <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

see: [Maven: System Dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies)

Comment: You should always avoid using system dependencies like this, they're not portable and will usually not work for a team.

Comment: Still have the problem, while building the project and run it with tomcat, seems like maven is not copying the jars files into the target\xxx-sanpshot\web-inf\lib folder, only while copying the files manually it works, any other solution how to make maven to copy the jars files to target folder?

Comment: In that case see here [Maven 2 assembly with dependencies: jar under scope “system” not included](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065928/maven-2-assembly-with-dependencies-jar-under-scope-system-not-included), probably you will end up with  @EngineerDollery suggestion (install dependencies in local repository!!!)

Comment: I was doing that, created a local repo, deploy the external jars into the @KLajdPaja local repo folder, but while deploying the war file, i cant see the eBay jars in the nested lib folder under target ( i can see all of the spring jars there) only while manually copying the jar files to the lib folder it is working, any idea how can i force maven to pack the local repo into the war file?

Comment: That's weird  because maven for generated wars copy's all dependencies unless scope is defined as provided

Answer (score 0):

The ebay SDK is on [bintray](https://bintray.com/ivan/maven/com.ebay.sdk)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ebay</groupId>
  <artifactId>sdk</artifactId>
  <version>883</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that ver 995, is out at https://go.developer.ebay.com/javasdk but not at bintray.. unfortunately seems like eBay not maintains there versions as they should ..