# maven create fat jar with external lib

Tags: maven, jar

I'm trying to create an executable jar, which contains my external jar.
    I have already read the articles mentioned below, but in my case, with this external jar I have to use the followings:
    
                #MYgroup#
                #myArtifact#
                #VERSION#
                system
                ${project.basedir}/lib/#myjar#.jar
            
    Because of the systemPath, I have to use scope system, and that's why, my jar won't be inlcuded in my final executable jar.
    When I try to run my jar, it will end up with NoClassDefFoundError to my external jar.
    Could you help my, how to include my external jar into my final runnable jar.

```
Here is my current plugins:
 <!-- compiler plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Make this jar executable -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>#MYMAINCLASS#</mainClass>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Copy project dependency , can be used when we have repository.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

Thanks you answer in advance!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven
https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/
```

Answer (score 0):

install your external jar manually to your repository, and then use the jar with default scope, and that would be simplest solution.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> \
                         -DgroupId=<myGroup> \
                         -DartifactId=<myArtifactId> \
                         -Dversion=<myVersion> \
                         -Dpackaging=<myPackaging>
```

And you can also refer possible other options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065928/maven-2-assembly-with-dependencies-jar-under-scope-system-not-included)